# How to handle caching counters by redis?

Tags: sql, postgresql, caching, redis

I am using `Postgres` as main DB and REDIS for caching. I am working on caching mechanism for one db query which takes to much time (It's about 5-6 JOINS + nested SELECTS). For now I am caching results of this query using `SET 'some key' JSON.stringify(query.result)`. This works fine, however I have one column that cannot be cached - it is called `commentsCount`. It has to be always up to date. As a temporary solution, I am querying db just for this one particular field like this:

```
app.get('/post/getBySlug/:slug',function(req,res,next){
   var cacheKey = req.params.slug+'|'+req.params.language; // "my-post-slug|en-us" for example
   cache.get(cacheKey, function(err, post){
      throw err if err;
      if(post) {
         db.getPostCommentsCount({ where: { id: post.id }}).done(function(err,commentsCount){
             throw err if err;
             post.commentsCount = commentsCount;
             res.json(post);
             next()
         })
      } else {
         db.getFullPostBySlug(req.params.slug, req.params.language).done(function(err, post){
            throw err if err;
            cache.set(cacheKey, post);
            res.json(post);
            next();
         })
      }
   })
})
```

But it is still now what I want, because main DB is still queried. Is there any standard/good practise on storing counters in REDIS? My comment insert function looks like this:

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO "Comments" VALUES (...) // insert comments
UPDATE "Posts" SET "commentsCount" = "commentsCount" + 1 WHERE "Posts"."id" = 123456 // update counter on post
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

I am using transaction because I dont want comment to be inserted without incrementing comments count. As a "side" question - is it better to make 2 sql queries in transaction or write a trigger to handle incrementing counter??

---

According to my query (I posted link to gist in comments):

1. We dont plan more than 2 languages (though it is possible)
2. I made those counters because I have to keep counters separate per language, be able to order by those separate counters and also be able to order by sum of the counters (total for all languages) - I found it hard to make query that would order by sum of columns from separate rows while still returning those rows... (At the begining counters were stored in language translations).
3. Generally this query looks for post where exists translation with specific 'slug' and 'language' (slug+language on post translation is unique index). Morover post has to be published (isPublished = boolean) and post.status has to be 'published' (status = enum) or post.iscomingSoon has to be true (isComingSoon = boolean). Do you have idea what index/ordering I could add to this query? Or should I just remove limit?
4. In every translation table I keep language as TEXT. It can be for example en-us or zh-cn etc. Do you think I should make it enum or maybe I should make another table to store languages and just keep language_id in translations?
5. Author actually can be null :)

Comment: If you can avoid it, you don't want to store `commentsCount` at all.  For one thing, it means that updates to `Posts` is completely serialized, per post (and _maybe_ adding comments).  This is derived information, which is a violation of good normalization practices.  A simple `COUNT(*)` like this is trivial to retrieve, assuming you have the requisite index on `Comments` - if you're just displaying it for stats, run a simple `SELECT` for the value without a lock, and accept that the number may be out of date (it could anyways, by the time it gets to the user).  That can be cached easily.

Comment: I forgot to tell that I have to order post by comments count (along with other conditions) - thats why I am storing this counter, to speed up ordering.

Comment: hmmm.... In order for that to be a viable strategy, you'd probably need an index starting with `commentsCount` (or in the proper order with the other conditions).  Which may thrash if rows are updated often.  How many rows (`Posts`, `Comments`) are we talking about here?  If I absolutely had to maintain the count I'd probably go with a trigger instead (although you effectively end up with the same issues).  I admit to being curious about your entire statement, because 5 or 6 joins isn't usually anything hard for a db.

Comment: Here is the query: https://gist.github.com/alekbarszczewski/0c0bcba38293abf22193 - however I lied to you - its 13 joins, and 4 SELECTS. It is generated by ORM + some parts are added by me. When I am testing it on heroku postgres it takes ~800-1200ms (Data set is pretty small 200 posts, 200 users, each post has 2 translations, there are total 10 series, 10 tags, no associations, etc ). Query is pretty complicated, I didnt set any indexes yet (except foreignKeys, unique keys on through tables, etc). For each translation table there is unique key on `slug+language`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm I dont know what is the size of raw data returned from DB, but data after ORM parsing/grouping is `19KB raw/3.3KB gziped` Maybe the amount of data returned from db to app is causing delay?

Comment: Hmm that might be an issue I think - I calculated RAW query result size (in fact I calculated result JSON size in bytes) and it is 823Kb - though I have not idea how Postgres packs and sends data back to client.

Comment: Okay, your first problem is going to be that you don't have any indices including non-key columns.  I don't see an `ORDER BY` in that query.  Unless you have a _very_ specific need, denormalizing count **per language** will hurt more than help - how many languages will you support?  `LIMIT` _without_ an ordering is worthless - either you only have one row (so is unnecessary), or it gives you a "random" row (whatever the optimizer picks first).  A number of those `LEFT JOIN`s should likely be regular `(INNER) JOIN`s - I find it unlikely a post doesn't have an author, for example.

Comment: At least some of that is fodder for _other_ questions.  Even if you end up denormalizing languages, you should still have language table.... hint, those aren't languages, those are combined language/regions.  The subquery for `Post` is only returning one row (period), so most of those joins should be pretty instantaneous (of course, you don't get to choose _which_ row, which is a problem...).  How would I know what you want the order to be?  That's something you decide in response to a business need.  Otherwise, I think I would have just classified translations as other posts, then linked them

Comment: Is there any tool for postgres that will tell me why my query is slow? Which part of it is slowest etc? I know there is explain, but it prints some data that I don't quite understand...

Comment: No, that's pretty much it; time to read a book.  Good luck!